# frame for the MKPolygonView is [[0,0][0,0]], or a dot, when adding a kml overlay to a MKMapView

Tags: ios, kml, mkoverlay

I am creating an iOS application for an iPhone, and am trying to add overlays on top of my map view. I am using Google Earth to create the paths that I want to use, and followed apples KMLViewer demonstration. The kml file seems to be parsed correctly according to apples instructions, and my code does not crash, but the frame MKPolygonView that is returned is [[0,0],[0,0]] and obviously is not displaying my path on the MapView.

Been trying to research and find a solution for a while with no luck.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Comment: Can you post some code please, for us to understand what might be going wrong?